# Grid is not using all the space available to it

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I began learning C# a few weeks ago in order to develop a UWP app. I am following Bob Tabor's tutorials "Windows 10 development for absolute beginners". He gives challenges while teaching so the we apply whatever we learn.

In his video no. 31, he gives a challenge. The idea is to make an app that looks like this:
[image: App image]

While solving this challenge, I came up with this mainpage.xaml. Just to give an overview, the black buttons on top and the image at the bottom is in mainpage.xaml. There also exists a frame in which different pages are shown depending on which button is clicked. And in the constructor of mainpage, I navigate to donuts.xaml.

This is my mainpage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Stupendous_Styles_Challenge.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Stupendous_Styles_Challenge"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="myButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 2, 0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="myIconStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 10, 0" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Name="DonutsButton" 
            Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"  
            Click="DonutsButton_Click">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/coffee-icon.png" Style="{StaticResource myIconStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Donuts" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="CoffeeButton" 
            Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Click="CoffeeButton_Click">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/donut-icon.png" Style="{StaticResource myIconStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Coffee" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="ScheduleButton" 
            Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" 
            Grid.Column="2" 
            Click="ScheduleButton_Click">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/schedule-icon.png" Style="{StaticResource myIconStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Schedule" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="CompleteButton"
            Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"
            Grid.Column="3" 
            Click="CompleteButton_Click">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/schedule-icon.png" Style="{StaticResource myIconStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Complete" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame Name="myFrame"></Frame>

        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Assets\background.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The problem is very silly. The app runs fine and look exactly like this. But when I resize the window, the middle (largest [the frame one]) part doesn't resize. Instead white border appears on the side. Something like this:
[image: The Problem]

Then, out of curiosity, I changed myFrame's background to Light Blue. The result was:
[image: Shock]

This meant that the frame actually got the full area. 
This is my donuts.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Stupendous_Styles_Challenge.Donuts"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Stupendous_Styles_Challenge"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="600">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0, 0, 0" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Slider" x:Key="mySliderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="Assets/white-logo.png" Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Original Glazed Count: " Style="{StaticResource myTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource mySliderStyle}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Speedway Special Count: " Style="{StaticResource myTextBlockStyle}" />
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource mySliderStyle}" />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Notice that the grid specifies "HorizontalAlignment" to "Stretch". Can someone help me figure out why is this happening?

Comment: Changing the width and height of the 'red' frame to be the same as the white/light blue frame I believe is what you are asking.  If you are using Visual Studio, there is width and height in the properties section. Note you can also change horizontal alignment in the property section to 'Fit to screen' or such and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: There is only one frame. The red one. I changed the width of the grid to be 960(I found that the frame was 960). But now the slider disappears @AleksandarZoric

Comment: Ah sorry.  Misunderstood.  If using VS, you can just drag the corners of the red frame to fit within the designated area.  Otherwise, find what is the total width of the app then what is the width of the image on the right - subtract that from the total app width which will then give you the width you need to put for the 'red' frame.  Same applied with height and the navigation buttons.

Comment: Didn't realize how it creeped in. Thanks a lot it worked. @Babbillumpa. Mind writing it as an answer so that I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set explicitly the width of the Page it will never stretch:

Remove `Width="600"`, alternatively you can set `MinWidth="600"`.

```
<Page
x:Class="Stupendous_Styles_Challenge.Donuts"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Stupendous_Styles_Challenge"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" MinWidth="600">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0, 0, 0" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve the issue, this is the edited version of donuts.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Stupendous_Styles_Challenge.Donuts"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Stupendous_Styles_Challenge"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="600">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0, 0, 0" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Slider" x:Key="mySliderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="Assets/white-logo.png" Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Original Glazed Count: " Style="{StaticResource myTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource mySliderStyle}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Speedway Special Count: " Style="{StaticResource myTextBlockStyle}" />
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource mySliderStyle}" />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

added this in the

```
<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

section:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I think the problem was that the grid inside the frame wasn't taking up the space it could get and had a fixed width, with the columndefinition added it does take all the space it can.

Comment: It doesn't work. @Babbillumpa pointed out the mistake. I don't now how but the page width was set to 600. Removing it worked